# How would I set message.presence.activities to show a second option?

Tags: discord.js

So I recently updated discord.js to v12 and I started fixing the code where it was throwing errors. I noticed that the users presence needed to be fixed although when I corrected it from `{message.users.presence.game || 'null...'}` to `{message.presence.activities ||'null...'}` the `'null...'` does not show if a user does not have a presence like it should do, instead it shows a blank line. Could this be because im missing something in the `message.presence.activities`? or have I set it incorrectly?. Here is an [image of a user without status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnKli.png) and an [image of a user with a status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Beblk.png)

Answer (score 0):

When `message.presence.activities` is empty it will display a blank line because in javascript empty arrays are still true, to get it to display `'null...'` you should change it to:

```js
message.presence.activities.length ||'null...'
```

The `.length` will check if the array contains any elements.

Comment: thanks its showing `'null...'` if they don't have one now, although is there a way to make it display 'custom status' or their set status if its not custom since the `.length` provides an integer if they have a status.

Comment: Yes you can do `message.presence.activities[0].name || 'null...'` if they're using a custom status it will display "Custom Status" and if they're not it will display their status, if you want to use something other than `name` you can check what other properties there are [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Activity)

Comment: its showing the `custom status` for those with one but logs this in the terminal `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` if they don't.